# How to crawl a website/extract data into database C# and SQLSERVER

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-crawler

I want to build an single cumulative webapp where users of my organization can use only one site instead of more than ten sites for different purposes.My organization have different sites for attendance,accounts,HR and many more.i want to crawl all these sites,read their data and save it in my sqlserver using c#,then user can use/search that data from my system directly.

```
How would that work?
What tools/libraries can/should I use?
Are there good tutorials on that?
How do I best deal with binary data (e.g. images)?
Are there already good solutions for that?
```

Comment: Why can't you just expose the data fm those other systems more directly, perhaps as web-services? Why would you want to duplicate their storage?

Comment: i tried  WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url); but this also give me issue..The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

The road you're heading down if fraught with problems. I'd never attempt it.  Consider these challenges:

- You'd have to parse the HTML which may or may not be well formed
- The data may be interspersed with all kinds of non-data (ads, navigation, hover text, javascript, comments, etc.)
- You have no idea of the age of the data
- The format of HTML for a given site may change from one day to the next and possibly break your previous scraping strategies
- Important information may exist on pages only accessed after satisfying an authorization step
- Data that used to live at one URL may have been moved around and is now living at a different URL or split up into several different URL's
- Some data may only be found if certain search parameters are entered or if certain users are logged in
- Users of your site might not be authorized (?) to view the data that you pull from the other sites

I'd recommend building a data warehouse and working with the providers of these systems to gain access to data feeds from their root databases (however that might be: REST URL's, direct SQL, web services, nightly data dumps).  Use ETL to xtract, ransform, and oad data from the raw database behind these systems.

Comment: Thanks for your kind info..yes i know all above drawbacks...i do not have access to their database and they do not have any api...the only way is to crawl their informations,save it to my db and then use it..daily i will run crawl